# extend SplFileObject with fread method

Tags: php

PHP5 introduced an object-oriented file wrapper, **SplFileObject**. I guess I just found out why hardly anybody is using it. It's purely line-oriented, there is no fread() method - which the corresponding frwite seemed to suggest.

So now I'm wondering if I can extend it. I'm however not sure what's the better workaround. SplFileObject is not particular helpful in tucking the file pointer ($fp) away - it's either a private attribute or ZE-internal resource. So how would I extend it to get a fread method?

- Implement fread() as string collecting **loop with fgets()**, with eventual seeking if only a specific size was requested and fgets read too far until the next \n line break.
- Use a custom constructor, which opens the file a second time and stores a **secondary file pointer**, in case I want to call fread() instead of the parent class methods.

I'd go for the fgets workaround loop, but it sounds cumbersome and slow and provides for more potential pitfalls. OTOH opening a secondary file pointer seems not a good approach either and needs a custom destructor too.

Comment: What do you need `fread()` for?

Comment: Reading the whole file. Just wanted to pass a file object around to have its meta information available.

Comment: In that case just add a method that calls `file_get_contents($this->getPathname());`. If you want to be able to use `fread` it's probably better just to define your own custom class that implements all the functionality you need using the file handling functions themselves.

Comment: Good idea. I'll add file_get_contents as extra method, since I'd be using that primarily. But anyway, I'd prefer a coherent file class. Reimplementing it at whole seems ill-favoured (also breaks SplFileinfo compat).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call extend it and add an `fread` method that calls the `fgetc` method repeatedly, the desired number of times.

That said, I agree this is a weird limitation. Submit a [feature request](http://bugs.php.net/). If I'm not missing something, and `fread` method ought to be implemented.

Comment: Yes, I guess the fgets workaround is the better approach. - Found indeed an open bug/feature request on php.net, some musings about a `SplBinaryFileObject` back in 2006, seemingly no actual plans to add it.

Answer (score 2):

Feature added in PHP5.6

. Added feature #65545 (SplFileObject::fread()) (Tjerk)

From https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-5.6.0RC2/NEWS